# ~/.bashrc change PS1 with color converts newline into carriage return first newline

Tags: bash, ps1

I changed my prompt as:

```sh
    c=$(basename $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)
    export PS1='[\h] -\e[0;36m$c\e[0;37m (\W)  \e[0;52m'
```

In `~/.bashrc`.

The first newline is actually carriage return but from the second newline these are actually newlines.

What I refer to the new line is when the command is too long and instead of continuing in a second line, I write on top of the beginning of the prompt line.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What newlines are you talking about? What is the "first newline"?

Comment: what are the expected and actual outputs?

Comment: @GordonDavisson first newline is when the command that I write is too long for one line and should start in a second line but instead is written on top of the beginning of the existing first line

Comment: @phuclv Sorry for the inaccuracies. I edited the question with the hope to make myself more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put escape sequences (or any other sequences that are invisible when printed) around `\[` `\]` for Bash to properly detect prompt length. See bash documentation about prompt.

Something along:

```
export PS1='[\h] -\[\e[0;36m\]$c\[\e[0;37m\] (\W) \[\e[0;52\]m'
```

*should* be fine - Bash should be able to handle multi-byte sequences and properly detect the length of UTF-8 stuff.

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk it works in bash. It does not work properly in mac as I update ~/.bash_profile. It would be great if you tell me how to make it work in mac too. THanks!